# Objective C - Turn static image on and off after button has been pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image

This is probably extremely easy, but how to do you make an image "flash" for about 10 seconds on and off then remain on in Objective C for iPhone.

I am using it in an IF statement, where if the button is pressed a choice of two images will appear. Once this has happened i want the images to go from hidden to unhidden and back for a few seconds.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSTimer in your view controller for this:

Create a timer with an interval of say, 10 sec:

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(showOrHideImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then implement a

```
-(void)showOrHideImage
```

In your "showOrHideImage" method, just toggle the hidden property of your UIImageViews.